# How to delete unnecessary points given a jointed path

Tags: path-finding

I'm writing code for client-side pathfinding, the player can setup more than one point and then pathfinding in segments finally get a concatenated path.(actually it's for the long distance pathfinding, you can setup some halfway points and the final dest, to travel the further position)

Here's the pathsmoothing code so far and it's in lua:

```
    local c = path.nextWork
while c + 1 < table.getn(path.finishedPath) do

    -- Points to test
    local p0 = coordToPoint(path.startPos, path.finishedPath[c-1])
    local p1 = coordToPoint(path.startPos, path.finishedPath[c+1])
    
    -- Has LOS
    if TheWorld.Pathfinder:IsClear  (
                                        p0.x, p0.y, p0.z,
                                        p1.x, p1.y, p1.z,
                                        path.pathcaps
                                    )
    then
        table.remove(path.finishedPath, c)
    
    -- No LOS
    else
        c = c + 1
    end
```

And the problem is that i found if i do path smooth for the concatenated path, (especially when some detours in the path),the result still exists some unnecessary point, the path smoothing code doesn't work well as expected.

For example, if i set a segment assisted point C like this and get a path that walk around a square obstacle, the expected smoothing result should be A-->E, but the code actual not remove the B and D. Note C point was marked by player and not required to be exactly on the final path.What i want is the code that make the jointed path without any redundant steps
[image]

Here's the similar situations in game(DontStarveTogether):
[image]

My expected path result:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why did you route A -> C then C -> E if you really wanted A -> E? A smoothing algorithm wouldn't eliminate major sections of the route like that, just remove redundant (or near redundant) vertexes. Which B and D clearly aren't because removing them would change the route significantly. It would remove C though, as that is redundant

Comment: actually , the path above has been simplified, A->C and C --> E are both much more complex than what is shown in the picture , and the one step pathfinding A-->E will exceed the search limit. C is marked in the map manunally by player to split the long distance pathfinding into segments , yes it's kinda strange to be there and should be between the A and E. the deviation of mark may cause some detours in the final path. I think the final path should be concise enough, and some detours insides should to be removed because E is the only destination for pathfinding

Answer (score 0):

You can define an "unnecessary" criterion which relies on how collinear a triplet of points are.  I'll use your `B`,`C`,`D` as an example.  You can use this to iterate over points starting from the first point until you have no further points.

To determine if `C` would be "unnecessary" you need to do some vector math.

```
local vecBD = {  x= D.x - B.x, y = D.y - B.y }
local lenBD = math.sqrt(vecBD.x^2 + vecBD.y^2)

local vecBC = { x = C.x - B.x, y = C.y - B.y }
```

You can then measure "how far off" `C` is from the line `BD` by projecting the `BC` vector component perpendicular to the line `BD`

```
local offBC = {
   x = vecBC.x - vecBC.x*vecBD.x/lenBD,
   y = vecBC.y - vecBC.y*vecBD.y/lenBD
}

local lenOffBC = math.sqrt(offBC.x^2 + offBC.y^2)
```

`lenOffBC` here is the distance `C` is off from the line `BD`.  You can discriminate on this value or on a value relative to the length of another distance, e.g. `BD` as `lenOffBC/lenBD`

If `C` is determined to be too close you remove it, and then repeat for `BDE`.  If `BDE` is "good" you move on and do the hypothetical `DEF` until you don't have three points anymore.